# How to prevent combine_latest firing multiple times when multiple inputs tick simultaneously?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

I'm using [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY)' [`combine_latest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) to perform an action whenever any inputs tick. The problem is if **multiple** inputs tick at the **same time** then `combine_latest` fires multiple times after each individual input ticks. This causes a headache because `combine_latest` is effectively ticking spuriously with stale values.

**Minimum working example** where a `fast` observable ticks every 10ms and a `slow` observable ticks every 30ms:

```
from rx.concurrency import HistoricalScheduler
from rx import Observable
from __future__ import print_function

scheduler = HistoricalScheduler(initial_clock=1000)
fast = Observable.generate_with_relative_time(1, lambda x: True, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x, lambda x: 10, scheduler=scheduler)
slow = Observable.generate_with_relative_time(3, lambda x: True, lambda x: x + 3, lambda x: x, lambda x: 30, scheduler=scheduler)
Observable.combine_latest(fast, slow, lambda x, y: dict(time=scheduler.now(), fast=x, slow=y)).subscribe(print)
scheduler.advance_to(1100)
```

Every 30ms, when `fast` and `slow` tick simultaneously, `combine_latest` fires twice undesirably -- the output is below:

```
{'slow': 3, 'fast': 2, 'time': 1030}  # <- This shouldn't be here
{'slow': 3, 'fast': 3, 'time': 1030}
{'slow': 3, 'fast': 4, 'time': 1040}
{'slow': 3, 'fast': 5, 'time': 1050}
{'slow': 6, 'fast': 5, 'time': 1060}  # <- This shouldn't be here
{'slow': 6, 'fast': 6, 'time': 1060}
{'slow': 6, 'fast': 7, 'time': 1070}
{'slow': 6, 'fast': 8, 'time': 1080}
{'slow': 9, 'fast': 8, 'time': 1090}  # <- This shouldn't be here
{'slow': 9, 'fast': 9, 'time': 1090}
{'slow': 9, 'fast': 10, 'time': 1100}
```

How can I prevent `combine_latest` from ticking spuriously?

Comment: No accepted answer so not technically a duplicate, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104268/combining-observables-when-both-change-simultaneously?rq=1) has answers that may be useful.

Comment: Could you use `withLatestFrom` in your situation? See http://staltz.com/rx-glitches-arent-actually-a-problem.html

Answer (score 2):

I think `debounce` does exactly what you want:

```
---A-B-C-----D------E-F----|->
  [debounce(some_interval)]
--------C-----D--------F---|->
```

After getting a value `A`, `debounce` will wait for `some_interval`. If another value `B` appears, it will emit `B` instead. So you could debounce your input stream, which will 'catch' those extra clicks and only emit the last one.

[More in the official docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)

(the question was asked a long time ago, but I'm answering it for future googlers.)

Comment: Here's a blogpost that explains it: https://blog.strongbrew.io/combine-latest-glitch/